# I Need To Exit Full Screen Area

Tags: osx

I accidentally pressed "Toggle Fullscreen Area" and im using a Mac so some things are different cause my keyboard and all I can think of is changing keyboards but can you help?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html?highlight=alt%20f10